# How to know the directory of folder where a file import b file but get the answer from b file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Goal

I want to get the directory file(b.py) which is importing another file(a.py). I know I can use os path pkg to get it when running b.py but I do not know how to set a function in a.py to get the answer. The example as below:

## File Structure

```
--a_folder
  -- a.py
--b_folder
  -- b.py
```

b.py import a.py . The `a.py` details below:

```
a.py 

def import_dir():
    # print the directory of file(b.py) which imports a.py.
    # the type of output is string.


b.py
import sys 
sys.append(../a_folder)
from a import import_dir  

import_dir # when run this line, it will get the directory of file(b.py).
```

Comment: So, you're looking to get the directory path of a Python file 'b' that is importing some other Python file 'a', from inside of a function call in 'a'? Can you tell use what the goal here is? Because there may be a simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do (which is only possible in specific cases).

Comment: why don't you get it as parameter - `def import_dir(folder):`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `os.path.dirname(__file__)` ?

Comment: I don't think so, because that gets them the path of the *current* file, while they are asking for the path to the file that performed the import.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.py 
import os

def import_dir(path=os.getcwd()):
    # print the directory of file(b.py) which imports a.py.
    # the type of output is string.
    print(path)


b.py
import sys 
sys.append(../a_folder)
from a import import_dir  

import_dir # when run this line, it will get the directory of file(b.py).
```